# Error response : Could not kill running container runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:392: init process caused "permission denied"

Tags: docker, containers, blockchain

When I tried to run `./byfn up in fabric-samples/first-network`, I am getting the following error.

> Error response from daemon: Could not kill running container
>   facc0618bbbe6741acf58167842b4a44f4749b69d9428936768959715c84c0fe,
>   cannot remove - Cannot kill container
>   facc0618bbbe6741acf58167842b4a44f4749b69d9428936768959715c84c0fe:
>   unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully:
>   container_linux.go:392: signaling init process caused "permission
>   denied"

I tried to reinstall `docker`, reload docker images, reload fabric-samples, checked at path but did not work out, can anyone light upon what causes to get this error, thanks.

Comment: try with "sudo"?

Comment: tried sudo also , same error, thanks..

Comment: the above issue is gone by firing the following commands 
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker 
but other problem + set +x
cat: log.txt: Permission denied

START


Build your first network (BYFN) end-to-end test

Channel name : mychannel
Creating channel...
!!!Channel creation failed !!!!!
 ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario

ERROR !!!! Test failed

Comment: may run with user root solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. But it has to be repeated everytime. Therefore, its not a good solution:

```
sudo killall containerd-shim
```

If its  still not working then delete everything and try again

```
sudo docker rm -vf $(sudo docker ps -a -q)
```

Try and if it stills complains then try:

```
sudo docker system prune -a
sudo docker rmi -f $(sudo docker images -q)
```

And if its still not working then delete the volumes as well